# How to keep just the first 300 charactes of every line?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I want to keep just the first 300 characters of every line.  The obvious solution:

```
sed -E 's/^(.{0,300}).*/\1/'
```

apparently exceeds some internal regex limit:

```
RE error: invalid repetition count(s)
```

Some experimentation shows rep count can only go up to 255, at least on my platform (MacOS).  Python can handle {0,300}, but I'd prefer to do this with normal shell tools, if possible.  Any ideas?

PS: Yeah, I know, if I was doing it in Python, I'd do line[:300] and ditch the regex completely.

Comment: perhaps writing: `.{0,255}.{0,45}` in place of `.{0,300}`. May the trick be with you.

Comment: The simplest way could be just to cut the string `cut -c -300 server.log`

Comment: Works for me with `mingw`. I was playing with `{0,300}` and `{1,300}`, both works well. So, which shell, which `sed` version do you use? Which lines cause the problems?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't error out for me on `GNU sed`, see if `cut` works for you

```
$ perl -e 'print "a" x 350' | sed -E 's/^(.{0,300}).*/\1/' | wc -L
300
$ perl -e 'print "a" x 350' | cut -c1-300 | wc -L
300
```